# Set and use variable outside of function in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, php-5.3, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a function that passes sales information to a third-party service via a SOAP API, and returns an array with the results.

I need to take a specific key from that array, set is as a variable or somehow use it outside of that function in other code.

I'm declaring the variable in a function, like so:

```
function foo { 
...code to sell product through API...

global $status;
$status = $checkoutShoppingCartRequest['Result']['Status'];
}
```

And here is statement where I need to use this variable, which fails every time:

```
if ( $status !== "Success") {
    $validation_result['is_valid'] = false;

    foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
        if ( $field->id == '1' ) {
            $field->failed_validation = true;
            $field->validation_message = 'Your credit card could not be processed.';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to this so any help's appreciated.

Corrected typo, in production code variable names were correct.

Comment: `$status` and `$mbStatus` ?

Comment: You can use session variable to store the status.and use outside the script

Comment: Sorry, the different variable names was just a typo in the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return the variable and use it like -

```
function foo() { 
...code to sell product through API...

...
$status = $checkoutShoppingCartRequest['Result']['Status'];
return $status;
}

$status = foo();
```

Then check.

```
if ($status !== 'Success') { .... }
```

Answer (score 1):

use the below code:

change `$mbStatus` to `$status`

```
if ( $status!== "Success") {
    $validation_result['is_valid'] = false;

    foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
        if ( $field->id == '1' ) {
            $field->failed_validation = true;
            $field->validation_message = 'Your credit card could not be processed.';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to return `status` from that function and use it outside.

```
function foo() { 
    //...code to sell product through API...
    return $checkoutShoppingCartRequest['Result']['Status'];
}

$status = foo();
if ( $status !== "Success") {
    $validation_result['is_valid'] = false;

    //for loop here
}
```

Avoid using `global`. `global` is evil.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `$status` outside the function in global scope:

```
$status = ''; // Global scope

function foo() {
    global $status; // Access the global $status var
    $status = 'status set in function';
}

foo();
print_r($status); // Outputs "status set in funciton"
```